# How to judge if an image is part of another one in Python?

Tags: python, image

This is how I tried:
(1) use PIL.Image to open the original(say 100*100) and target(say 20*20) image and convert them into np.array;
(2) start from every pixel in the original one as a starting position, crop a 20*20 area and compare every pixel RGB with the target. 
(3) If the total difference is under certain given level, then stop and output the specific starting pixel position in the original one.

The problem is, step(3) costs over 10s which is much too long, even step(2) costs over 0.04s and I hope to optimize my program. In both steps I used For to iterate array, is there a more efficient way?

Comment: More efficient than what? Difficult to tell, without [seeing your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Having said hat - this sounds rather like  an example for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare two signals (or images) at different displacements one can use [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).

If you have the [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) package you can use 2D cross-correlation to measure how similar the two images are when you *slide* one image over the other.
This example is copied from the [correlate2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html) function:

```
from scipy import signal
from scipy import misc
lena = misc.lena() - misc.lena().mean()
template = np.copy(lena[235:295, 310:370]) # right eye
template -= template.mean()
lena = lena + np.random.randn(*lena.shape) * 50 # add noise
corr = signal.correlate2d(lena, template, boundary='symm', mode='same')
y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr), corr.shape) # find the match
```

If you don't want to use a toolbox you could implement the cross-correlation yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I want. BTW, match_template from skimage.feature can also solve this with a normalized xcorr matrix as output